# Error while Renaming files in folder

Tags: file, directory, rename

After hours of reading online and implementing different codes, I came to below conclusion.

I have a folder name **111646** and in that folder, file names are like **1-foto-000.jpg?20160331103045**

What I am trying to do is rename file name to **1-foto-000.jpg**

I am using below code.

```
<?php

          $files = scandir('111646/');

          foreach($files as $file) {

                $newname = explode("?", $file);

                rename($file, $newname[0]);

           }
?>
```

When I run the above code, it gives me error

```
Warning: rename(1-foto-000.jpg?20160331103045,1-foto-000.jpg): No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sunuti/index.php on line 17
```

The code is trying to rename file but it shows the wrong directory path in error.

I think there is very small mistake but I could not find it out...

Help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

rename() is executing in your folder, you need to specify that you want it to run in the subfolder. 
Try:

```
<?php
      $folder = '111646/'
      $files = scandir($folder);

      foreach($files as $file) {

            $newname = explode("?", $file);

            rename($folder.$file, $folder.$newname[0]);

       }
```

?>